# laravel 6 - task schedule withoutOverlapping still overlapp with heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I try to run a task withoutOverlapping but the task still called every minute even if i add

```
->withoutOverlapping()
```

Here is my task i have a sleep(240) to force the task to be longer than 1 min but the mails is still sent every minutes

```
 $schedule->call(function() {
        $user = User::find(4);
        Mail::to('john.doe@gmail.com')->queue(new AccountConfirmation($user));
        sleep(240);
    })->name('update_game')->withoutOverlapping(20);
```

I use heroku with a scheduler here are the logs : [image] the task "update_game" run every minutes even if the task takes more than 1 minute (with the sleep(240)) i wonder why

Comment: What cache driver are you using?

Comment: I use the default  cache driver (file)

Comment: It is because you are passing a parameter to your withoutOverlapping method. You are telling it not to overlap for only 20 seconds. `->withoutOverlapping()` or `->withoutOverlapping(240)`

Comment: the parameter for withoutOverlapping is in minutes not in seconds https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps apparently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Heroku scheduler starts **a brand new dyno** (basically, a server) every time it runs.

`->withoutOverlapping()` only applies to the current server, so it's not doing anything, because the next minute *another* server is running.

You'll want to call `->onOneServer()` too, but to do that, you'll need to move off the `file` driver onto something like `redis` for your caching system, or you'll have the same problem - one server not knowing anything about the other, because they each have their own set of files.